# Osmolality and osmolarity of infant formula

Tags: solutions, concentration, colligative-properties

Actually, this question is about the following sentence, which I have seen (in various forms) in numerous papers (e.g. [this one](https://fn.bmj.com/content/104/3/F333.full?ijkey=UiwzZi7yNBF9td1&keytype=ref) and [this one](https://www.cjhp-online.ca/index.php/cjhp/article/view/3033/4289)):

> The American Academy of Pediatrics advises that formulas for normal infants should have an osmolarity no greater than 400 mOsm/L (approximately 450 mOsm/kg).

I searched Google up and down but could not find the calculation or the conversion between osmolarity and osmolality of infant formulas. I might be missing something, but does anyone know or can find the relationship between those two values?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_concentration the relation includes the plasma density and the dry content per volume.

Answer (score -1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_concentration):

Osmolarity = osmolality * (ρsol − ca)

where:

- ρsol is the density of the solution in g/ml, which is 1.025 g/ml for blood plasma.[5]
- ca is the (anhydrous) solute concentration in g/ml – not to be confused with the density of dried plasma

p.s. I am surprised that the osmolarity and osmolality differ that much in numeric value. For other (non-medical) purposes I considered them almost interchangeable.